# How do you maintain your url after a function is used?

Tags: url, jsf, navigation, managed-bean, faces-config

I'm having a problem with my url.
First, I have to display the image and the information of the image
But I need to click on a button to display my information.

This is the link with the image displayed and information not being displayed.
portal/faces/chicken.jsp?image_id=1

So, after i clicked the button. It becomes portal/faces/chicken.jsp

My code for retrieving the image needs the url image_id=1 as I'm using
request.getParameter("image_id") to display out the image.

This is the code for my button from the jsf:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean1.checkwork}" value="Get Info" type="submit">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{param['image_id']}"></f:param>
</h:commandButton>
```

This is the code for my faces-config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/MainPage.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{bean1.checkwork}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>successful</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>chicken.jsp?image_id=#{param['image_id']}</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

This is the code for my function.

```
      public String checkwork()
      { 
           HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)
           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
           String image_ID = null;
              if(request!=null)
              {
                   image_ID = request.getParameter("image_id");

                   images(image_ID);
                  student(matric);

               }
          else
          {
               System.out.println("fail");
                }

    return "successful";

}
```

So, does it have anything to do with the jsf, managed bean or the faces-config.xml?
Anyone knows the problem with my code?

Comment: Why don't you render image information using ajax?

Comment: Well, I'm not taught to use ajax before, because this is actually a school assignment based on netbeans. Im using a tomcat server, jdbc connection, mysql, managed beans, servlet, jsp and jsf. So... yeah.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will indeed not appear in the URL anymore when you press the button, because the command button sends a POST request with the parameter in the request **body** instead of request URL. So the request parameter is definitely available. With a HTTP traffic checker (press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug) you can see it.

Your concrete problem is caused because you assigned the `<f:param>` a wrong name.

```
<f:param name="id" value="#{param['image_id']}"></f:param>
```

This way it would only be available by `request.getParameter("id")`, not by `getParameter("image_id")` as you attempted. Fix the name accordingly:

```
<f:param name="image_id" value="#{param['image_id']}" />
```

As to your concrete question about maintaining the URL after a "function" ("function" is the wrong term, you probably meant "method", "action method") is used, just use GET instead of POST. Use `<h:button>` instead of `<h:commandButton>`. You'll only need to change the code to invoke the actual action in (post)constructor or `<f:event preRenderView>` of the bean associated with the target view.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there are nicer ways to grab it in your backing bean.

```
String imageId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("image_id");
```

Having `javax.servlet.*` imports in your JSF code is namely a sign that you're doing things possibly the clumsy way. Note that the `request` is **never** null (how else would the JSF code be executed?), so that nullcheck on `request` is also completely unnecessary.

Another way is using `@ManagedProperty`:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{param.image_id}")
private String imageId; // +setter
```

This works only on a request scoped bean though.